# Create link to main page (.Net, MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, actionlink

I have a .Net MVC 3-Application and have a controller named SupplierController which administers two views (pages), a list and an edit view for suppliers.
In the list view, I created Edit-links like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<RyfMvcTestApplication1.Models.DataModel.Model.Supplier>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

In the edit view, a back link was automatically created

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
</div>
```

but this leads to the root page (http://localhost). I would like to get the list page, which has to the url http://localhost/Supplier. The best I worked out so far is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index/Supplier")
```

but this leads to the url http://localhost/Supplier/Index/Supplier, which is not what I want.

My SupplierController:

```
public class SupplierController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Supplier> suppliers = sr.GetAll();

        return View("List", suppliers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my routing configuration. It looked like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Supplier", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
    }
```

If I change the default controller in the MapRoute-method to something else, all works fine.
I don´t know why this should be a problem and would be thankful for comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following overload allowing you to specify the action and the controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Supplier")
```

Comment: This also leads to the root url (http:localhost) :(

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl, well, then use the controller and action you wish. If you have defined the Supplier controller and the Index action in your Default route definition as default values then it is normal that they will be skipped. `/` will be exactly the same as `/supplier` and exactly the same as `/supplier/index` => it will hit the same controller action so it doesn't really matter. If you want to use a different controller/action simply specify them.

Comment: But if I use the SupplierController (as posted in my question), should it not return the view "list"?

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl, yes, it will, since that's the view that the Index action returns. When you generate urls, you only work with controllers and actions. Views are never visible to the outside. You can return any view you like from the given action but the url will point to this action.